# Upload file to WEBPAGE without openfile dialog user intervention

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, security

I have a google webpage that has a BROWSE button. When one clicks it an openfile dialog appears and prompts the user to select a file for uploading.

The problem is that the client has a lot of files and field to complete so I first tried to automate this through a browser extension. All worked well besides the file uploading. It seems tht because of security reasons you can't make a browser extension, feed it the path of the filename, and automatically upload it.

I want to automate this upload, field-auto-completion process, **INSIDE A .NET APPLICATION**,  How do I access webpage DOM objects in .NET?

Is there a .NET library that can sweep through and modify DOM nodes as easily as you could inside a browser extension with the added possiblily of automating the BROWSE button openDialog stuff?

Comment: No browser will allow you to do that. as far as security is concerned this a breach.

Comment: @user, Can I do it in .NET? is there a library that accesses DOM objects as easily as a browser extension would?

Comment: No, you won't be able to do it using a web app. your best bet if to use a different method to upload the files to the server.

Comment: no ASP.NET. A windows form program can't do this? The client installs the app just for this purpose what would be the security risk in that?

Comment: if you choose windows forms, you will have to use a transfer protocol to upload the files to your webserver. FTP is the easiest way to achieve this.search SO for FTP using winforms or google the same.